# ASP.Net MVC AJAX upload file to controller is being submitted twice

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC application. I need to send a file to Controller with ajax. but I have twice request.

```html
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "MyController", new { area = "" },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnBegin = "onBegin",
        OnSuccess = "onSuccess(data)"
    }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "myform" }))
    {

    <section class="col col-md-12">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
        <label class="input">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title)
        </label>
    </section>

    <section class="col-md-6">
        <label class="label text-left">
            My File
        </label>
        <label for="file" class="input input-file">
            <div class="button">
                <input name="files" type="file" id="file" onchange=" this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value ">choose...
            </div>
            <input type="text" readonly="" class="text-right">
        </label>
    </section>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Submit
    </button>
}
```

Controller Action, When posting my data using AJAX, here's twice request in my Action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase files, CreateViewModel model)
{
    // The Request comes here twice.
}
```

and my references in page,

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

```js
$(function () {
    $('#myform').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: ShowRequest,
        success: SubmitSuccesful,
        error: AjaxError
    });
});

function ShowRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    var queryString = $.param(formData);

    alert('BeforeSend method: \n\nAbout to submit: \n\n' + queryString);
    return true;
}

function AjaxError() {
    alert("An AJAX error occured.");
}

function SubmitSuccesful(responseText, statusText) {
    alert("SuccesMethod:\n\n" + responseText);
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: Shouldn't you change button type from 'submit' to 'button'?

Comment: No, It does not matter

Comment: You have `Ajax.BeginForm()` which does an ajax submit, and then you also have `$('#myform').ajaxForm()` which does another ajax submit. Change it to `Html.BeginForm()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using ASP.NET MVC AjaxForm as well jQuery ajaxForm plugin. When you press submit button, the request is sent by MVC as well jQuery.